# Why NodeMcu is disconnecting every 2 sec?

Tags: arduino, nodemcu

**Summery**

I recently bought a nodemcu 1.0 (ESP8266 12-E). It was working fine before this noon. But, now it's disconnecting every 2 sec.

**Description**

Until this noon I successfully run the blink code and some other codes. But, now when I connect the board to PC, PC plays a sound and immediately after 2 sec It disconnects from PC. If I keep open arduino software i can see the `com 4` for a split sec but, then It disconnects. When I unplug it and replug the cable same happens again.

**Things I tried**

I did try to update arduino software as well as nodemcu drivers from http://www.wch-ic.com/downloads/CH341SER_ZIP.html

Updated the arduino software to 1.8.15 which is current latest release.

Comment: If none works, then try replacing the board. It might be permenantly damaged.

Comment: Could also try it on another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is rather tricky to be answered. I faced the same situation a while before and got some cases.

**Drivers**

As you mentioned, You updated drivers from  http://www.wch-ic.com/downloads/CH341SER_ZIP.html which is CH340G/CH341 drivers. It is possible that you might have CH340G chip in your board but, the board comes with another variant as well(cp2102). You can download the drivers from [here](https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers).

**Software**

You did update the software but, it is likely not the case which is disconnecting the board. Software is medium through which you can access the board.

**Hardware**

It is possible that one of the component in your board is damaged. It can be possible. Unless you are a pro at hardware you cannot figure out what's causing the issue.

Still, there is a possibility that serialization chip is damaged. And you can use FTDI driver for that. You can buy that from market easily.

**YOUR PC**

It is very rare but, Yes it is quite possible that actually your pc is damaged or usb port is damaged. In my case usb port was damaged and was not supplying enough current to board and then it was disconnecting automatically.

If above mentioned scenario doesn't work then I highly recommend that check the board with other PC.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and cable was the culprit. Just change the cable, hope it will work.